# Running an external application WITHOUT administrator right from a C# application that has administrator right

Tags: c#, administrator, privilege

I have written C# application that needs administrator privilege. So I manually changed the property of its executable to run as administrator. So it is running as administrator.

Now, this executable needs to run an external application. When I use Process.start(...); command the external application is automatically executed with administrator privilege. This is not good for my purpose.

Is there anyway to run the external application without administrator right from C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the application under another user:

```
Process p = new Process("...");
p.StartInfo.UserName = "...";
p.StartInfo.Password = "...";
p.Start();
```

Comment: What if there is no other user?

Comment: Sorry, this solution would only work if you were able to create an account with the appropriate permissions to run the application